# Python not writing to file

Tags: python, datetime

I'm making a script that reads through a .txt file and then proceeds to use that information, and the date, to create dynamic html files. It worked yesterday, but today, it seems like it doesn't want to write anything to the file...

Here is the source code.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os
import io
import shutil
import datetime
import random
import re
from apiclient.http import MediaIoBaseUpload, MediaIoBaseDownload
from datetime import date
from apiclient import discovery
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools

def filerino():

    daginfo     = str(datetime.datetime.today().weekday())
    ukenr       = (datetime.datetime.today().isocalendar()[1])
    dato        = datetime.date.today()
    day         = datetime.date.today().day
    month       = datetime.date.today().month
    yesterday   = (day - 1)
    tomorrow    = (day +1)
    todayerino  = str(day) + "/" + str(month)
    yesterdayerino = str(yesterday) + "/" + str(month)
    tomorrowerino = str(tomorrow) + "/" + str(month)
    currentweek = (datetime.datetime.today().isocalendar()[1])
    lastweek    = ((datetime.datetime.today().isocalendar()[1]) - 1)
    currentweekerino = "Uke " + str(currentweek)
    lastweekerino = "Uke " + str(lastweek)



    file=open("plan.txt", "r")
    if daginfo == "3":
        daginfo = ("Matte\n" + "Naturfag\n" + "Engelsk\n" + "ToF\n")
        dag = ("Torsdag")
        imorgen = ("Fredag")
    elif daginfo == "0":
        daginfo = ("Samfunnsfag\n" + "Geografi\n" + "Norsk / Engelsk\n")
        dag = ("Mandag")
        imorgen = ("Torsdag")
    elif daginfo == "1":
        daginfo = ("Naturfag\n" + "Spraak\n" + "Engelsk\n" + "Matte\n")
        dag = ("Tirsdag")
        imorgen = ("Onsdag")
    elif daginfo == "2" and ukenr %2 == 0:
        daginfo = ("Gym\n" + "Matte\n" + "Norsk\n")
        dag = ("Onsdag")
        imorgen = ("Torsdag")
    elif daginfo == "2" and ukenr %2 != 0:
        daginfo = ("Gym\n" + "Matte\n")
        dag = ("Onsdag")
        imorgen = ("Torsdag")
    elif daginfo == "4":
        daginfo = ("Spraak\n" + "Norsk\n" + "Engelsk\n" + "ToF\n")
        dag = ("Fredag")
        imorgen = ("Laurdag")
    elif daginfo == "5":
        daginfo = ("Ingen fag idag, siden det er HELG! :D")
        dag = ("Laurdag")
        imorgen = ("Saundag")
    elif daginfo == "6":
        daginfo = ("Ingen fag idag, siden det er HELG! :D")
        dag = ("Saundag")
        imorgen = ("Mandag")


    file=open("plan.txt","r")
    s = file.read()
    dayresult = ((s.split(str(tomorrowerino)))[1].split(str(todayerino))[0]).strip()
    dayresult = dayresult[:dayresult.rfind('\n')]
    lines = re.split("\n", dayresult)
    timeserino = dayresult.count("\n")
    try:

        fagTitle = {}
        for x in range(-1, timeserino):
            x += 1
            fagTitle[x] = lines[x]

        fagContent = {}
        for x in range(-1, timeserino):
            x += 1
            fagContent[x-1] = lines[x]

        if timeserino == 1: #if there is 1 lines within the two dates.
            file=open("/testfolder/index.html", "w")
            file.write("""
           <!doctype html>
           <html lang="en">
           <head>

             <meta charset="utf-8">

             <title>InstaPlan</title>

             <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
           </head>

           <body>
               <div class="jumbotron" id="nbn">
                 <h1 id="sub">""" + (dag) + """ """ + str(dato.day) + """/""" + str(dato.month) + """ """ + """Uke""" + """ """ + str(ukenr) + """:</h1>
                 <h1 id="mid"><small>""" + (daginfo) + """</small></h1>
               </div>
               <div class="jumbotron" id="nbn">
                 <h1 id="mid"><small>Lekser til """ + (imorgen) + """:</small></h1>
               </div>
               <div class="jumbotron" id="nbm">
                 <h1 id="sub">""" + fagTitle[0] + """</h1>
                 <h1><small>""" + fagContent[0] + """</small></h1>
               </div>
           </body>
           </html>
           """)
        elif timeserino == 3: #if there are 3 lines within the two dates.
            file=open("/testfolder/index.html", "w")
            file.write("""
           <!doctype html>
           <html lang="en">
           <head>

             <meta charset="utf-8">

             <title>InstaPlan</title>

             <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
           </head>

           <body>
               <div class="jumbotron" id="nbn">
                 <h1 id="sub">""" + (dag) + """ """ + str(dato.day) + """/""" + str(dato.month) + """ """ + """Uke""" + """ """ + str(ukenr) + """:</h1>
                 <h1 id="mid"><small>""" + (daginfo) + """</small></h1>
               </div>
               <div class="jumbotron" id="nbn">
                 <h1 id="mid"><small>Lekser til """ + (imorgen) + """:</small></h1>
               </div>
               <div class="jumbotron" id="nbm">
                 <h1 id="sub">""" + fagTitle[0] + """</h1>
                 <h1><small>""" + fagContent[0] + """</small></h1>
               </div>
               <div class="jumbotron" id="nbm">
                 <h1 id="sub">""" + fagTitle[2] + """</h1>
                 <h1><small>""" + fagContent[2] + """</small></h1>
               </div>
           </body>
           </html>
           """)
        elif timeserino == 5: #if there are 5 lines within the two dates.
            file=open("/testfolder/index.html", "w")
            file.write("""
           <!doctype html>
           <html lang="en">
           <head>

             <meta charset="utf-8">

             <title>InstaPlan</title>

             <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
           </head>

           <body>
               <div class="jumbotron" id="nbn">
                 <h1 id="sub">""" + (dag) + """ """ + str(dato.day) + """/""" + str(dato.month) + """ """ + """Uke""" + """ """ + str(ukenr) + """:</h1>
                 <h1 id="mid"><small>""" + (daginfo) + """</small></h1>
               </div>
               <div class="jumbotron" id="nbn">
                 <h1 id="mid"><small>Lekser til """ + (imorgen) + """:</small></h1>
               <div class="jumbotron" id="nbm">
                 <h1 id="sub">""" + fagTitle[0] + """</h1>
                 <h1><small>""" + fagContent[0] + """</small></h1>
               </div>
               <div class="jumbotron" id="nbm">
                 <h1 id="sub">""" + fagTitle[2] + """</h1>
                 <h1><small>""" + fagContent[2] + """</small></h1>
               </div>
               <div class="jumbotron" id="nbm">
                 <h1 id="sub">""" + fagTitle[4] + """</h1>
                 <h1><small>""" + fagContent[4] + """</small></h1>
               </div>
           </body>
           </html>
           """)

        elif timeserino == 7: #if there are 7 lines within the two dates.
            file=open("/testfolder/index.html", "w")
            file.write("""
           <!doctype html>
           <html lang="en">
           <head>

             <meta charset="utf-8">

             <title>InstaPlan</title>

             <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
           </head>

           <body>
               <div class="jumbotron" id="nbn">
                 <h1 id="sub">""" + (dag) + """ """ + str(dato.day) + """/""" + str(dato.month) + """ """ + """Uke""" + """ """ + str(ukenr) + """:</h1>
                 <h1 id="mid"><small>""" + (daginfo) + """</small></h1>
               </div>
               <div class="jumbotron" id="nbn">
                 <h1 id="mid"><small>Lekser til """ + (imorgen) + """:</small></h1>
               <div class="jumbotron" id="nbm">
                 <h1 id="sub">""" + fagTitle[0] + """</h1>
                 <h1><small>""" + fagContent[0] + """</small></h1>
               </div>
               <div class="jumbotron" id="nbm">
                 <h1 id="sub">""" + fagTitle[2] + """</h1>
                 <h1><small>""" + fagContent[2] + """</small></h1>
               </div>
               <div class="jumbotron" id="nbm">
                 <h1 id="sub">""" + fagTitle[4] + """</h1>
                 <h1><small>""" + fagContent[4] + """</small></h1>
               </div>
               <div class="jumbotron" id="nbm">
                 <h1 id="sub">""" + fagTitle[6] + """</h1>
                 <h1><small>""" + fagContent[6] + """</small></h1>
               </div>
           </body>
           </html>
           """)
    except IndexError: #if it detects an IndexError because there either aren't any lines between the dates
        file=open("/testfolder/index.html", "w")
        file.write("""
       <!doctype html>
       <html lang="en">
       <head>

         <meta charset="utf-8">

         <title>InstaPlan</title>

         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
       </head>

       <body>
           <div class="jumbotron" id="nbn">
             <h1 id="sub">""" + (dag) + """ """ + str(dato.day) + """/""" + str(dato.month) + """ """ + """Uke""" + """ """ + str(ukenr) + """:</h1>
             <h1 id="mid"><small>""" + (daginfo) + """</small></h1>
           </div>
           <div class="jumbotron" id="nbn">
             <h1 id="mid"><small>Lekser til """ + (imorgen) + """:</small></h1>
           </div>
           <div class="jumbotron" id="nbm">
             <h1 id="sub">ayylmao</h1>
           </div>
       </body>
       </html>
       """)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    filerino()
```

It writes to a file called index.html. I think the problem lies in the Try statement, but I tried to remove it and it didn't affect it in any way.

Thank you.

Comment: I'd post just the snippet of the section within the post, not in pastebin.

Comment: Like @haifzhan said, Close that file handle when you're finished!  `file.close()`.

Comment: @haifzhan how would I go about doing that? And why would it suddenly stop working?

Comment: So I closed the file after the writing is finished, but that didn't fix the problem. I don't know if was supposed to fix the problem, but either way, the problem still stands

Comment: @Toasterino see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) make sure it meets any of the scenarios. you didn't have `else` condition as below, your timeserino may not meet any of your 1-7 scenarios

```
if timeserino == 1:
   # write something
elif timeserino ==2:
   # write something
...
elif timeserino == 7:
   # write something
else:
   write something
```

2) close your file when you finish writing

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have fixed it. However, it's weird, because it should fullfill the requirement today :/

Answer (score 1):

Your fundamental problem is that your function is too long and complex and you're not able to debug it (or understand why it is failing).

Easy refactorings that will make the intention clearer are things like naming expressions that are used often (e.g. `datetime.datetime.today()`) and using arrays to select something from a sequence instead of a long cascade of if-statements:

```
today = datetime.datetime.today()
weekday = today.weekday()
dagnavn = ['Mandag', 'Tirsdag', 'Onsdag', 'Torsdag', 'Fredag', u'Lørdag', u'Søndag']
dag = dagnavn[weekday]
```

then tomorrow can be selected similarly:

```
imorgen = dagnavn[(weekday + 1) % 7]
```

having eliminated dag and imorgen from the if statement, `daginfo` can be assigned in a more descriptive manner using daynames instead of weekday numbers:

```
daginfo = {
    'Mandag': "Matte\n" + "Naturfag\n" + "Engelsk\n" + "ToF\n",
    'Tirsdag': "...",
    ...
}[dag]
```

your code to this point is one "unit" that can stand alone (which you seem to instinctively understand by the paragraph-like spacing). It should be pulled out into a separate function so the original function gets smaller and easier to reason about (a function should normally not be longer than you can fit on your screen without scrolling).  A function would look like:

```
# dagnavn is a constant and should be defined at module level
dagnavn = ['Mandag', 'Tirsdag', 'Onsdag', 'Torsdag', 'Fredag', u'Lørdag', u'Søndag']


def get_schedule(date):
    weekday = date.weekday()
    dag = dagnavn[weekday]
    imorgen = dagnavn[(weekday + 1) % 7]
    daginfo = {
        'Mandag': "Matte\n" + "Naturfag\n" + "Engelsk\n" + "ToF\n",
        ...
    }[dag]
    return dag, imorgen, daginfo
```

then you would remove the long if statement in `filerino()` and replace it with:

```
dag, imorgen, daginfo = get_schedule(today)  # still assuming you've created the `today` variable
```

If you keep pulling out code "units" like this into their own functions, you'll eventually end up with a much smaller function that exhibits your problem. That, smaller function, is what you would normally post in a question on SO (the smallest possible piece of code that demonstrates your problem).

Comment: Thanks for the nice feedback. I'm quite aware that my code is probably awful and a nightmare to read for experienced programmers, but I'm just starting out, and doing the best I can with what I know. I have limited amount of time to make this work properly so I won't rewrite it now, I just need to make sure I have a functioning build first. However, when I've demonstrated and presented my product, I will probably rewrite it like you suggested, due to the fact that I'm going to keep working on it. Again, thanks for the feedback, and the time you took to write it as understandable as possible :)